# How to set several repeating alarm at exact interval with several unique ID?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-dialog, android-alarms

> The fact is, I need to register an user, set two alarm for his/her with the interval of 30 minutes and 4 hours. I set the interval 3 and 4 minutes for testing. I was supposed to use an Dialouge Activity to show alarms to get some input. The problem i am facing are as follows:
>
> 1. When there are multiple user and have their corresponding alarms(both), alarms are showing scattered.
> 2. After a while only the latest users alarm is showing.
> 3. Even after some time only one alarm of both of an user is showing only.
> 4. Suddenly the Dialouge Activity is showing error to set style "Theme.AppTheme"
>
> Pending Intent:

```
  Intent alarmIntent4 = new Intent(Settings.this, AlarmReceiver.class).putExtra("id", id4);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Settings.this, Integer.parseInt
                    (id + "4"),
            alarmIntent4, 0);
    AlarmManager manager4 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager4.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            4 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            pendingIntent4);

    Intent alarmIntent30 = new Intent(Settings.this, AlarmReceiver.class).putExtra("id", id30);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent30 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Settings.this, Integer.parseInt
                    (id + "3"),
            alarmIntent30, 0);
    AlarmManager manager30 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager30.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30 * 60 * 1000,
            pendingIntent30);
```

> Alarm Receiver:

```
  Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(500);

    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Intent i = new Intent(context,DialogActivity.class).putExtra("id",id);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

> [My Dialouge Activity Class](http://ideone.com/scSfBt).
>   I know the things about exact or inexact alarming facts for versions upper than Lollipop. But i need to solve the problems mentioned on top. Please help.